# CentOS7 : Need to restart SoftEther VPN interface to have my static IP

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, vpn, systemd-networkd

i start my VPN client (softEther) with SystemD a OS startup and i have trouble to assignate a static IP to the local interface of vpn client network interface.

There is my SystemD config :

```
    [Unit]
    Description=SoftEther VPN Client
    After=network.target auditd.service
    ConditionPathExists=!/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient/do_not_run

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    EnvironmentFile=-/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient
    ExecStart=/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient start
    ExecStop=/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient stop
    KillMode=process
    Restart=on-failure

    # Hardening
    PrivateTmp=yes
    ProtectHome=yes
    ProtectSystem=full
    ReadOnlyDirectories=/
    ReadWriteDirectories=-/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient
    CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_BROADCAST CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SYS_NICE CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_SETUID

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i start the service, local interface appear but without the static IP that i configure.

```
    vpn_softether: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::2ac:e9ff:fe7e:289e prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:ac:e9:7e:28:9e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
    RX packets 12 bytes 864 (864.0 B)
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX packets 20 bytes 1632 (1.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

There is my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-vpn_softether :

```
DEVICE="vpn_softether"
HWADDR="00:ac:e9:7e:28:9e"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO=static
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
IPADDR="10.38.0.50"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
```

I need to execute an :

```
    ifdown vpn_softether && ifup vpn_softether
```

to be able to have my static IP on the interface :

```
    vpn_softether: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.38.0.50 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.38.0.255
    inet6 fe80::2ac:e9ff:fe7e:289e prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:ac:e9:7e:28:9e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
    RX packets 33 bytes 2506 (2.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX packets 69 bytes 12308 (12.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I will appreciate some tips :)

Comment: Put the commands in a script and reference the script in ExecStart

Comment: good idea ! can i add execstart directive on my systemD vpnclient service ? Or i need to create a new one ?

Comment: Add /usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient start and  ifdown vpn_softether && ifup vpn_softether to a script and then reference that created script on the ExecStart line in your systemd service file

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient start
ifdown vpn_softether && ifup vpn_softethe
```

to a script and then reference that created script on the ExecStart line in your systemd service file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Raman !

It could help someone, there is the tricks.

Modified systemD service :

```
    [Unit]
    Description=SoftEther VPN Client
    After=network.target auditd.service
    ConditionPathExists=!/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient/do_not_run

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    EnvironmentFile=-/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient
    ExecStart=/usr/local/vpnclient/restart_vpn_eth.sh
    ExecStop=/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient stop
    KillMode=process
    Restart=on-failure

    # Hardening
    PrivateTmp=yes
    ProtectHome=yes
    ProtectSystem=full
    ReadOnlyDirectories=/
    ReadWriteDirectories=-/usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient
    CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_BROADCAST CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SYS_NICE CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_SETUID

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the script :

```
    #!/bin/sh

    /usr/local/vpnclient/vpnclient start
    sleep 5
    ifdown vpn_cent
    sleep 5
    ifup vpn_cent
```